# Can't load xlsx file

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to read attached xlsx ([Click here to download](http://kulkarniabhishek.weebly.com/uploads/2/2/1/1/221164/test.xlsx) ) file using python openpyxl. However, workbook cannot be loaded. Here is my attempt to open xlsx file in python -

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> workbook = load_workbook(filename = "test.xlsx")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 136, in load_workbook
    _load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, use_iterators, keep_vba)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 198, in _load_workbook
    keep_vba=keep_vba)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 332, in read_worksheet
    fast_parse(ws, xml_source, string_table, style_table, color_index)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 320, in fast_parse
    parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 137, in parse
    dispatcher[tag_name](element)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 176, in parse_merge
    self.ws.merge_cells(mergeCell.get('ref'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet.py", line 815, in merge_cells
    raise InsufficientCoordinatesException(msg)
openpyxl.shared.exc.InsufficientCoordinatesException: Range must be a cell range (e.g. A1:E1)
```

Comment: Did you save the file as `xlsx` using excel, or saved it as `xls` and changed the extension to `xlsx` manually by renaming the file? Did you use `Excel` or `OpenOffice/LibreOffice` equivalent? The equivalents enable extra-features that are not Excel-compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some merged cells were, in fact, merged with themselves. openpyxl expected a merged cell reference always to be a range of cells. A fix for the problem which ignores meaningless merges has been added to the 2.0 branch.

Answer (score 4):

**It appears that your `.xlsx` file is damaged or permanently corrupted.** The reasons could be many. One of them could be that you might have renamed the extension of the file to `.xlsx` which would invalidate the file. To confirm this beahviour, please try to open this file in Microsoft Excel.

I tried reading the file through, `openpyxl`, `xlrd` and `pandas` but none of them worked.

```
>>> import xlrd
>>> xlrd.open_workbook('test.xlsx')
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '<html> <'


>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> workbook = load_workbook(filename = "test.xlsx")
InvalidFileException: File is not a zip file

>>> import pandas 
>>> pandas.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
InvalidFileException: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: Yep! I created an empty file and changed the extension to .xlsx and was getting the same error. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue trying to open every file in a directory ending in  *.xlsx .
I later found the file that caused the error was named ~$filename.xlsx .  I'm guessing that Microsoft  indicates that a file is currently opened by creating a file with the same name, prepended with the ~$.  Once I closed the file, everything worked as expected.

Comment: That's a completely unrelated issue but, yes, Microsoft Office creates a shadow file every time it opens a file.

Comment: I searched this forum for the error: "InvalidFileException: File is not a zip file"   and found this thread-  I later discovered the file I was trying to read was the shadow file. Yes, I'm a newbie trying to build up my reputation.  Disappointed that you knocked me down for sharing my experience regarding this error.

Answer (score 0):

I like `openpyxl` and use it for creating `xlsx` documents. It could be a bug or a missing compatibility with excel feature that takes place in your specific document. I would report it to the `openpyxl` community

Answer (score 0):

OK Guys.. I have reported this bug to openpyxl developers and they have provided a quick fix on this. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/issue/316/openpyxl-cannot-load-attached-workbook) is the complete thread.

Comment: Yes the link by developers has been removed now... however this is fixed in openpyxl 2.0

Answer (score -1):

I did never try `openpyxl` but I use `xlrd` for reading excel files (.xls and .xlsx). its work great.

see the examples and documentation at http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, openpyxl provides many good functions which I am already using for parsing multiple tables from xls sheet to convert into python dictionary. I have written a generic parser for the same. I cannot revert back the generic code and rewrite using xlrd. I got this problem with this file only.